# LokiJS autoloadCallback not woking

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I am trying to use my existing DB in LokiJS but my autoloadCallback does not fire.

Am using `console.log('from add collection don')` to know when it fires but it never does and when I try to add data to the DB it fails. It only works when I set my collection variable locally:

```js
  var user = null
      db = new loki("myuser.json",{adapter: adapter}, {
        autosave: true,
        autosaveInterval: 5000,
        autoload: true,
        autoloadCallback: function(){
            db_ready = true;
            console.log('from add collection don')
            if(db.getCollection("myaccount") == null ){
                myusers = db.addCollection("myaccount");
            }
       
        }
    });
```

```js
function py_userlogin(username,password,islogin){
        myusers.insert({
            username:username,
            password:password,
            islogin:islogin
        },function(err,don){
            console.log( JSON.stringify(err) + JSON.stringify(don))
        });
        console.log(myusers.data);
        db.saveDatabase();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting options in a third variable that is not present, it should be only:

```
new loki(file, [options]);
```

`adapter` is an option just like the others, like this:

```
var user = null
      db = new loki("myuser.json",{
        adapter: adapter,
        autosave: true,
        autosaveInterval: 5000,
        autoload: true,
        autoloadCallback: function(){
            db_ready = true;
            console.log('from add collection don')
            if(db.getCollection("myaccount") == null ){
                myusers = db.addCollection("myaccount");
            }

        }
    });
```

Cheers